# How to write a recursive formula?

Tags: summation, recursion, command-line

What is the Mathematica command for the recursive formula:

```
   F[a_]:=Sum[(-1)^a Binomial[a,k] Log[2]^(a-k) F[k], {k,0,a}]
```

where

```
 F[0]=Log[2]
```

Thank you,

The latex formula is

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{a}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1+x}dx=(-1)^a \int_0^1\frac{\ln^{a}\left(\frac{2x}{1-x}\right)}{1+x}dx$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^a \binom{a}{k}\ln^{a-k}(2)\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{k}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1+x}dx$$

which, by the way, follows from subbing $x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$ then using the binomial theorem.

Comment: You cannot determine `F[a]`, where $a$ is even from these equations. For instance  you get for $a=2$: `F[2]==F[2] - 2 F[1] Log[2] + F[0] Log[2]^2`. Your question has no solution.

Comment: Can you give what the output should be for say `F[2]` or `F[3]`?  Also it is `Binomial` not  `binomial`

Comment: Please include $\LaTeX$ for your formula to facilitate disambiguation.

Comment: @Syed sure I will

Comment: @yarchik sorry it is $(-1)^a$ not $(-1)^k$.

Comment: When `a` is even, the even terms vanish in the recursive formula.It means that we can not only using this recursive formula to deduce all the terms.

Comment: If anyone is interested, the first terms can be found directly after observing `Log[x/(1 - x)] == Log[x]-Log[1-x]` :

`tTab=Table[Integrate[(Log[x] - Log[1 - x])^a/(1 + x), {x, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 
  4}]`

`(*{Log[2], -(1/2) Log[2]^2, 
 1/3 Log[2] (\[Pi]^2 + Log[2]^2), -(1/4) Log[
   2]^2 (2 \[Pi]^2 + Log[2]^2), 
 1/15 Log[2] (\[Pi]^2 + Log[2]^2) (7 \[Pi]^2 + 3 Log[2]^2)}*)`

I have gone up to $a=10$ and tried using `FindSequenceFunction` but with no luck.

Looking at the form of `tTab//Expand` is also interesting and may lead somewhere

Comment: Using a change of variables `t = Log[x]-Log[1-x]`, you can also generate this a little faster with `Table[Integrate[(1/(1 + E^t) - 1/(1 + 2 E^t)) t^a, {t, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}], {a, 0, 4}]`

Comment: @RolandF I verified it so please double check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It is impossible to deduce all the terms from the original recursive formula.

```
r1 = Block[{a = 1}, 
  F[a] - Sum[(-1)^a Binomial[a, k] Log[2]^(a - k) F[k], {k, 0, a}] == 
    0 // FullSimplify]
r2 = Block[{a = 2}, 
  F[a] - Sum[(-1)^a Binomial[a, k] Log[2]^(a - k) F[k], {k, 0, a}] == 
    0 // FullSimplify]
r3 = Block[{a = 3}, 
  F[a] - Sum[(-1)^a Binomial[a, k] Log[2]^(a - k) F[k], {k, 0, a}] == 
    0 // FullSimplify]
r4 = Block[{a = 4}, 
  F[a] - Sum[(-1)^a Binomial[a, k] Log[2]^(a - k) F[k], {k, 0, a}] == 
    0 // FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Observe the first 4 recursive formulas. We can see that we can deduce `F[1]` from `F[0]` by `r1` or `r2`( actually `r1` is equivalent to `r2`).

And  we can also deduce `F[3]` from `F[0],F[1],F[2]` by `r3` or `r4`, but we still cann't deduce `F[2]`. (BTW, under the condition of `r1`, the `r3` and `r4` are equivalent)

- The expression of `f[2]` as below indicate that `f[2]` it is unlikely can be deduce from `f[0]` and `f[1]`.

```
f[a_] := Integrate[(Log[x/(1 - x)])^a/(1 + x), {x, 0, 1}];
{f[0], f[1], f[2]}
% // N
Table[NIntegrate[(Log[x/(1 - x)])^a/(1 + x), {x, 0, 1}], {a, {0, 1, 
   2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you  and sorry its $(-1)^a$ not $(-1)^k$ in the OP.

Comment: @AliShadhar  How to  deduce the  recursive formula ?

Comment: I just added some steps in the OP showing how I came up with it.

Comment: Very clear thank you. So basically this formula shows only relations among these integrals.